# Python Websocket 2-Way Communication

Tags: python, websocket

I'm able to get connected and authenticated to the WebSocket, but am unable to send any requests after that.

I'd like to be able to send messages to the server to perform different actions. Upon connection the `on_open(ws)` runs as expected, and I'm returned the confirmation `on_message` that I'm authenticated. But after that I can't seem to do anything else.

If I put `ws.send(MESSAGE)` before the `ws.run_forever()` the WebSocket closes before it can send. If I put it after, the WebSocket seems to hang.

So my question is, how do I go about sending the WebSocket commands after it's connected and authenticated?

```
import websocket
import json

def on_open(ws):
    print("Connection Opened")
    authenticationMsg = {
        "action": "authenticate",
        "data": {
            "key_id": "KEY_ID",
            "secret_key": "SECRET_KEY"
        }
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(authenticationMsg))

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(json.loads(error))

def on_close(ws):
    print("Connection Closed")

socket = "wss://data.alpaca.markets/stream"
ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(socket, on_open=on_open, on_message=on_message, on_error=on_error, on_close=on_close)
ws.run_forever()
```

As a side note, calling the Websocket from CLI rather than in a script gives me the prompt to enter messages and works allows back and forth communication as expected:

```
zackscomputer % python3 -m websocket wss://data.alpaca.markets/stream
Connected to wss://data.alpaca.markets/stream.
>
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you can throw things into the `on_open()` function and that will continue even though the `on_message` function is called anytime there's a message.

I could have sworn I tried this, but getting away from the screen for a while seems to have helped.

```
def on_open(ws):
    print("Connection Opened")
    authenticationMsg = {
        "action": "authenticate",
        "data": {
            "key_id": config.alpacaApiKey,
            "secret_key": config.alpacaApiSecretKey
        }
    }
    ws.send(json.dumps(authenticationMsg))

    subscribe = {
        "action":"listen",
        "data": {
            "streams": [WHATEVER I WANT HERE]
        }
    }

    ws.send(json.dumps(subscribe))
```